# Is there any way to call only one rule within a SaltStack state?

Tags: saltstack

I have a state called `service.sls` within an "elasticsearch" directory. I could call the entire state via `salt-call state.sls elasticsearch.service` but I'd only like to trigger one rule within that state.

Context: the config is `file.managed` and has been changed but I'd like to manually do the restart that the state would trigger.

Answer (score 1):

You can do [`salt-call state.high`](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.state.html#salt.modules.state.high) and specify the individual rule that you want from the file directly on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Although there is an `exclude` parameter to most state functions, there isn't an `inclue`.
You could however exclude all other state ids to only execute the "rule" you want:

`salt-call state.sls elasticsearch.service exclude="[{'id': 'id_to_exclude'}, {'id': 'id_to_also_exclude'}]"`